# JQuery - toggle background colour of css styled radio buttons label

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the below piece of code, which applies some css to some radio buttons. This works fine.
However, I need a way so that when I right click one of the buttons, it toggles the background colour to red.

```
<script>
$('body').on('contextmenu', '.checkItem', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Toggle Colour here
    }
</script>

<style>
.checkItem
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 12em;    
    height: 64px;
    margin:5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.CheckItem label
{
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #EDEDED;
    padding:5px;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    height: 48px;
}

.checkItem input[type=radio]:checked + label 
{
    background: #CCFFCC;
    color: #000000;
}
</style>

<div class="checkItem">
    <input class="input_checkItem" type="radio" name="n_radio" value="34" id="0" checked="checked">
    <label for="0">button1</label>
</div>

<div class="checkItem">
    <input class="input_checkItem" type="radio" name="n_radio" value="35" id="1" checked="">
    <label for="1">button2</label>
</div>
```

I tried adding a class with:

```
$(this).children("label").addClass('colRed');
```

but this didn't work. The class appeared, but the colour didn't change.

The closest I have got is with:

```
$(this).children("label").toggle(function () 
        {
            $(this).children("label").css({'background-color' : '#CC9999'});
        }, function () {
            $(this).children("label").css({'background-color' : ''});
        })
```

But this sets the 'label' to '`style="display: block;"`' whereas I would have expected '`style="background-color":"#CC9999"`'

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

jquery css-functionm work like so:

```
 $( this ).css( "color", "red" );
```

So what you want should be something like this:

```
$(this).children("label").css('background-color' , '#CC9999');
```

check out that page for more info: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: `$(this).children("label").css({'background-color' : '#CC9999'});` and this is also a valid. Is used when you want to place multiple parameters at the same time, such as `$(this).css({'overflow': 'hidden', 'height': '60px'})`

Comment: cheers, but these still have the affect of setting the label to display:none rather than changing the colour

Comment: I Hope ".CheckItem label" is a typo, watch out for the Css-Class-Case

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's not as clean as using '`toggle`', but it seems to work:

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', '.checkItem', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($(this).children("label").hasClass('ignore'))
            {
                $(this).children("label").removeClass('ignore')
                $(this).children("label").css('background-color' , ''); 
            }
        else
            {
                $(this).children("label").addClass('ignore')
                $(this).children("label").css('background-color' , '#CC9999');
            }
    })
```

why the `.toggle` didn't work I don't know. But for the moment I have a way to do this.